# Can't find module 'request' when running a node

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I'm trying to run a nodejs file, but whenever I run it, I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'request'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\njtest\web-api-auth-examples-master\authorization_code\app.js:11:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

I had a similar error with a different module, and all I did was download it and the error went away, but I downloaded the request module, and I'm still getting the error. I have all the files from [here](https://github.com/request/request) downloaded and in the file path C:\Users\USer\Documents\njtest, and it shows the Request Master folder. This is for trying to do authentication with the spotify API by the way. Any ideas on to why it's still giving the error? I'm guessing maybe the file needs to be somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a package.json file along your "main" file, with the "requests" module listed as a dependency? Then use `npm install` to install the dependency

Comment: @AntoineBolvy I see a few package.json files. How do I check to see if  requests is listen as a dependency?

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I just used npm install to install the things needed and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I found that my request package was declared in `devDependencies` in `package.json` automatically and when I declared it in the `dependencies` object instead, this resolved the issue for me.

If yours is in `dependencies` already, that may not be your issue, but it is worth checking.

Regarding the difference in the two objects, `devDependencies` and `dependencies`:

> The difference between these two, is that devDependencies are modules which are only required during development, while dependencies are modules which are also required at runtime.

(https://medium.com/@dylanavery720/npmmmm-1-dev-dependencies-dependencies-8931c2583b0c)